# Htaccess rewrite rule causing Forbidden access

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to hide subfolders from url like this:

**localhost/imo/public_html/public/ajuda.php** to **localhost/imo/ajuda**

Its working well if the file exist, if not i get a forbidden access like this:

> You don't have permission to access
>   /imo/public_html/public/public_html/public/public_html...public/contacto.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php
>   on this server.

this is my htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ public_html/public/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public_html/public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA,NC]

</IfModule>
```

I already search on stackoverflow and it seems that the rules is causing a loop but the solutions provided didn't work on my case so far. Any help at all would be very aprecciated.

Thank you.

**UPDATE**
Thanks to @Matthijs Otterloo this is the working htaccess script:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ public_html/public/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public_html/public
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)$ /public_html/public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA,NC]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: I'd rather recommend you set up proper Virtual Hosts and local testing domains instead.

Comment: like, using something like http://imo/ instead of http://localhost/imo/ ???

Comment: Ok. i did learn about virtual host and i set up a imo.cv domain for my project . Now i have **imo.cv/ajuda** working but the problem persist if i point to a none existing file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this in your `.htaccess` file:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public_html/public
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)$ /public_html/public/$1 [L]`

Best way would be to set-up propper virtual hosts but this should fix it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. add this lines after: **RewriteRule ^$ public_html/public/**
now return : **The requested URL /public_html/public/ajuda was not found on this server**

Comment: Can you tell me more about setting up virtual hosts please?

Comment: Ok sir, it worked. I did set up a virtual host and manage to work my htaccess better with your solution. I will update my question to put the modified htaccess. Thanks a million times.